# How to add shadow image effects on a picture in Microsoft Word

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word

Using Python 3, I used `document.add_picture` to bring an image to my word document file, and now I need to format this image, adding a shadow image effect and a 1/4 pt border line (both are native Microsoft Word effects), so image 1 becomes image 2, someone knows how can I do this?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

The shadow effect in Microsoft Word is in picture format > picture effects > shadow > Offset: Bottom Right[image: Shadow Effect]

And the border effect is in picture format > picture border > weight > 1/4 pt [image: picture border]

Could someone help me with adding this effects through Python 3 ? I don't know if there's a library or something like that in Python to do this

Comment: What Python package did you use to do `document.add_picture`?

Comment: @Trilarion Thank you for your reply, I used ```from docx import Document``` and ```from PIL import Image```

Comment: Have you had a look in the [documentation of the docx package](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if they can achieve what you want?

Comment: You could also ask directly at their [issue tracker](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues). Maybe they would consider adding that functionality if it isn't already present.